# IS there a simple way to get the current Azure Search index name programatically?

Tags: content-search, indexing, azure-search

I need to get the current active index name for Sitecore search for logging purposes. Because of the swap on rebuild functionality, I can't simply use the name field of the index, since on alternating rebuilds the name will change from the default to something like `sitecore-master-index-1234`. Searching Sitecore SE, it seems like there is no simple of way doing this. I went so far as to look at the disassembled code of `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure`, and it seems the field storing this name is marked internal so no one can access it outside of Sitecore.

Is there really no way to get this index name easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call the [Azure Search Rest API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) directly to query the `index-catalog`

Example request:

```
GET xxx.search.windows.net/indexes/index-catalog/docs?search=*&$filter=sitecorename eq 'sitecore_web_index'
```

Result:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "key": "SITECORE_WEB_INDEX-SEARCH",
            "sitecorename": "sitecore_web_index",
            "indextype": "SEARCH",
            "servicename": "sitecore-web-index-815"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "key": "SITECORE_WEB_INDEX-REBUILD",
            "sitecorename": "sitecore_web_index",
            "indextype": "REBUILD",
            "servicename": "sitecore-web-index"
        }
    ]
}
```

The result with `indextype` of `SEARCH` will give the current active index definition, you can then use the `servicename` for the index name.